# active record joins and match on all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I need to update this query from matching all of 4 and 1 to include all posts where user 4 and user 1 commented on the same post

This is my bad Active record query

`Posts.joins(:commentors).where(commentors: {user_id: ["","4", "1"]})`

Comment: You could eager load the relation. `Posts.includes(:commentors).references(:commentors).where(commentors: {user_id: [...]})`.

Comment: Thanks but that is returning all that includes "1 or 4" not "1 and 4"

Comment: you could use raw sql in there where clause. `where('commentors.user_id IN (?)', [...])`

Answer (score 0):

```
user_ids = {}.compare_by_identity
user_ids['user_id'] = [1]
user_ids['user_id'] = [4]

Posts.includes(:commentors).references(:commentors).where(commentors: user_ids)
```

Hope this works!